# GSON fromJson is not assigning values to the Java fields

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Json string `"{"value":"3A72fd4ccb-1980-26cf-8db3-9eaadf1205c2"}"`, 
while passing the same string to the below code:

```
Gson headerGson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Object  ob = headerGson.fromJson(jsonStr, cl);
```

The resultant object is not getting assigned to the "value" is json string.
When I tried to print the object field using ReflectionAPI I got:
The fields are :value
Corresponding field type --> class java.lang.String
Corresponding value is --> null

The java class that I passed as "cl" in the fromJson method is as below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AttributedURI", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class AttributedURI {
@XmlValue
@XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
protected String value;
@XmlAnyAttribute
private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

/**
 * Gets the value of the value property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the value property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

/**
 * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
 * 
 * <p>
 * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
 * the value is the string value of the attribute.
 * 
 * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
 * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
 * 
 * 
 * @return
 *     always non-null
 */
public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
    return otherAttributes;
}
```

}

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: What does that class have to do with that JSON? I see nothing in common. --- The JSON is one object with a field named `MessageID`. Since `AttributedURI` doesn't have a field with that name, nothing is mapped.

Comment: The MessageID parameter is a type of AtributedURI, and that AttributedURI has a field named value, so fromJson method is taking "{"value":"3A72fd4ccb-1980-26cf-8db3-9eaadf1205c2"}" & AttributedURI class as arguments.
Please let me know if I am clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `AttributedURI` is represents the inner part of your json: `{"value":"3A72fd4ccb-1980-26cf-8db3-9eaadf1205c2"}`. So, when you're executing method`headerGson.fromJson(jsonStr, cl)`, Gson is trying to find `MessageID` field in the `AttributedURI` class, which is obviously absent.
To deserialize your json, you could wrap `AttributedURI` in other class. For example:

```
public class OuterClass {
    @SerializedName("MessageID")
    private AttributedURI messageID;

    public AttributedURI getMessageID(){
          return messageID;
    }
}
```

I also doubt that you need XML annotations here: afaik, GSON works doesn't need them.

Also, `Gson#fromJson` is generic method, so you can write:

```
 OuterClass  ob = headerGson.fromJson(jsonStr, OuterClass.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Currently I am passing the following parameters to the fromJson method like this:
jsonStr = {"value":"3A72fd4ccb-1980-26cf-8db3-9eaadf1205c2"}
fromJson(jsonStr, AttributedURI.class)
Still I am getting the value filed as null from the returned object. 
Please let me know if I am clear.

Comment: I'm not sure what goes wrong in your case. Here is a short snippet, it runs successfully for me (I persist your annotations, although it works without them):
      
  https://github.com/wirelessMousetail/sandbox/blob/stackoverflow-61205132-answer/src/main/java/GsonTest.java

Comment: Also, pay attention, that you need a `SerializedName` annotation in outer class (like in example above), because `MessageID` field is started from uppercase, and in java you should start variable names with lowercase.

Comment: I had to use JsonObject.get() to get the object and then .toString() for Gson.FromJson().